# Observer always triggered when app come from background

Tags: android, android-livedata, observers

I use the `livedata` in a Fragment that is in a viewpager. I observe a liveData in the `onActivityCreated()` and display the data in a list. So far so good and I have no problem. On the other hand, when I put the application in background and return to any page of my viewpager, the `Observer` is called again and I don't understand why! Please help me understand. I don't even go through the `onResume()` of the fragment in question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see in the Image attached, the lifecycle of the Fragment is little different than that of activity, in fragment going to the background result in calling of following functions:

```
onPause() -> onStop() -> onDestroyView()
```

and when called back to the view it calls following functions

```
onCreateView() -> onActivityCreated() ->  onStop() -> onResume()
```

Hence the observer is called again in onActivityCreated() method. If you want your observer should not be called again, you should add it in onCreate() method of the respective fragment.

[image]

Comment: thanks man ! I have a better understanding of fragment life cycles and activity now. I will try in the OnCreate()

Comment: Yes, give it a try and if its work, do come back and mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

LiveData considers an observer, which is represented by the Observer class, to be in an active state if its lifecycle is in the STARTED or RESUMED state. LiveData only notifies active observers about updates. Inactive observers registered to watch LiveData objects aren't notified about changes.

Comment: How can I know the state of the lifecycle of the fragment?

Comment: if you mean "to learn" then try here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments, if you mean why is this happening ... when your app returns from background your fragment is RESUMED and your observer "sees" the LIVEDATA 'again',

Comment: so why doesn't my fragment go through `onPause()` when I put the application in background from an adjacent page?

Comment: how do you know what states your fragment is going through? do you have extensive logging in all you fragments lifecycle methods? have you looked at the lifecycle diagram I linked to?